# want to design review table for restaurants

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Want to know which appropriate fields to use in review table.

requirement for review table:

```
    > review will be given by customer
      * review in points
      * review in description
      * review in videos (instead of text can upload review video in which it present review description)
      * comments on reviews.
      * restriction to display review in public or not
    > review for menuItem
    > review for restaurants
    > review for packs / coupns available
```

can any one help me who has worked on review system.

Comment: Ok, so is it for a menuitem OR a restaurant? or is it always a menuitem (that belongs to a restaurant)? Where did you get stuck? can you give some usecases? what have you tried, what is the issue?

Comment: can review for menuItem and/or restaurants tooo

Comment: Please update your question to have all the information: take some time and put in some effort to write use-cases. While doing that, you will come up with some sort of idea of how to do this. Write this down. tell us how you think this might be inadequate. This is just "My boss says I need to make this, please do my work for me"

Comment: @Nanne : no i can design but why i asked is that when some one has experience working on review then they are able to identify exact fields that are required as well as they have implemented that in real scenario and have solved most of the problems too. SO I AM EXPECTING BEST FROM EXPERIENCE DEVELOPER SO I DON'T HAVE TO FACE THE PROBLEMS IN FUTURE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my senior suggestion its need to be like this:

**user_reviews**

```
  - id
  - restaurant_menu_item_id    
  - restaurant_id
  - customer_id
  - review_title        : title like wow / superb / or ...
  - review_points       : from 1 - 10
  - description         : limit it to ...
  - review_video_id         
  - created_bye
  - created_date
  - update_date
  - status
```

I think this works fine for now as well as future (i mean it allow me to change in future if required)

Answer (score 0):

`Review` Table Contains

```
 1. reviewId (INT, Primary key, Auto Increment)
 2. restaurantId (INT, ForeignKey of restaurant table)
 3. userId (INT, ForeignKey of user_master table)
 4. menuItemId (INT, ForeignKey of menuItem table)
 5. couponId (INT, ForeignKey of packs / coupons table) 
 6. title (VARCHAR)
 7. comment (VARCHAR or TEXT)
 8. reviewePoints (TINYINT)
 9. reviewedOn (DATETIME)
 10. status (TINYINT)
```

Comment: where i store how much review done and comments of it all those thing. have you implemented this

Comment: @murtaza.webdev I had added the `comments` column and If i want to find no of reviews done than I can find using query on the review table

Answer (score 0):

**review table** contains

```
review_id (pk,autp_increment)
user_id(fk references usier_id in user table)
```

**menu_items_reviews table** contains

```
id (pk,auto_increment),
review_id (fk references review_id in review table),
review_desc (text or varchar(xxx))
```

this is similar for all other types reviews like restaurants and packs / coupns available

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements, business rules and application high level design. However you can start with a sample design I am putting up for you.
You must have following tables to enforce these requirements at bare minimum level.

1. User table ( containing following fields UserId, Name, Phone, EMail)
2. Menu table ( containing following fields MenuId, Description)
3. MenuItem table ( containing following fields MenuItemId, MenuId, ItemId,CategoryId)
4. Item table ( containing following fields ItemId, ItemName, Description, Price, IsActive, IsSpecial)
5. MenuCategory table ( containing following fields CategoryId, CategoryName, Description,  IsActive)
6. Review comment table ( containing following fields ReviewId, ReviewComment, ReviewRating, UserId, MenuItemId, ReviewDate)
7. Restaurant table ( containing following fields RestaurantId, Name, AddressLine1, AddressLine2)
8. RestaurantMenu table (containing following fields RestaurantMenuId, MenuId, RestaurantId)
9. Coupon table (containing following fields CouponId, Description, StartDate, EndDate, isActive, RestaurantId, [Discount%])

   ```
   USE [YourDBName]
   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Coupon]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Coupon](
       [CouponId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
       [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
       [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
       [isActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
       [RestaurantId] [int] NULL,
       [Discount%] [real] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Coupon] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [CouponId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Item]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
       [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [ItemName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
       [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
       [Price] [money] NOT NULL,
       [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
       [IsSpecial] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [ItemId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Menu]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu](
       [MenuId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Menu] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [MenuId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MenuCategory]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MenuCategory](
       [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [CategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
       [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
       [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MenuCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [CategoryId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MenuItem]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MenuItem](
       [MenuItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [MenuId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [itemid] [int] NOT NULL,
       [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MenuItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [MenuItemId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Restaurant]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Restaurant](
       [RestaurantId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
       [Addressline1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
       [Addressline2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Restaurant] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [RestaurantId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RestaurantMenu]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RestaurantMenu](
       [RestaurantMenuId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Menuid] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Restaurantid] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_RestaurantMenu] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [RestaurantMenuId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Review]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Review](
       [ReviewId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [ReviewComment] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
       [ReviewRating] [real] NOT NULL,
       [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [MenuItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [ReviewDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Review] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [ReviewId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 1/8/2014 12:44:59 PM ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
       [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
       [Phone] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
       [Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [UserId] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Coupon]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Coupon_Restaurant] FOREIGN KEY([RestaurantId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Restaurant] ([RestaurantId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Coupon] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Coupon_Restaurant]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MenuItem_Item] FOREIGN KEY([itemid])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Item] ([ItemId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MenuItem_Item]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MenuItem_Menu] FOREIGN KEY([MenuId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MenuItem_Menu]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MenuItem_MenuCategory] FOREIGN KEY([CategoryId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[MenuCategory] ([CategoryId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MenuItem_MenuCategory]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RestaurantMenu]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RestaurantMenu_Menu] FOREIGN KEY([Menuid])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RestaurantMenu] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RestaurantMenu_Menu]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RestaurantMenu]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RestaurantMenu_Restaurant] FOREIGN KEY([Restaurantid])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Restaurant] ([RestaurantId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RestaurantMenu] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RestaurantMenu_Restaurant]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Review]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Review_MenuItem] FOREIGN KEY([MenuItemId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[MenuItem] ([MenuItemId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Review] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Review_MenuItem]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Review]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Review_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Review] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Review_User]
   GO
   ```